# Como buscar APP RStudio Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Estou entrando no mundo do Rstudio Shiny agora. Uma duvida que me surgiu é a seguinte: como busco os Shiny Apps disponiveis/criados? Todos os Apps criados estão disponiveis? Há alguma forma de, uma vez criado meu app, eu impedir que ele seja visualizado? Ou durante a criacao eu "bloquea-lo"?

De tanto procurar encontrei esse link via site do Rstudio: http://www.showmeshiny.com/

Essa seria a plataforma de busca de todos os apps feitos?

Mas no caso do http://www.showmeshiny.com/ me parece que é necessario envia-lo via "Submit App".